# Parse query AND operator on the server

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using Parse to send push notifications and need to send to users who are subscribed to 2 channels: one main channel and at least one of a list of secondary channels.
Tried to use just one query like suggested in Parse forum but it didn't work :(

```
//query main channel
var query1 = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query1.equalTo('channels', main);
//query secondary channels
var query2 = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query2.containedIn('channels', secondaryList);
//desired result
ParseQuery mainQuery = ParseQuery.and(query1, query2);
Parse.Push.send({ 
              where: mainQuery,
              data: {
                alert: req.body.message,
                uri: req.body.url
             }
            }, {
              success: function() {
                console.log("Push was successful");
              },
              error: function(error) {
                console.error(error);
              }
            });
```

Comment: Use query.equalTo 2 times, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

No such thing as Query.and().  Get conjunction by qualifying a single query:

```
var justOneQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
justOneQuery.equalTo('channels', main);
justOneQuery.containedIn('channels', secondaryList);
Parse.Push.send({ 
          where: justOneQuery,
          // ...
```

Since both tests are about the contents of the channels column, presumably an array, then the single query can be qualified with a single condition:

```
var main = "foo";
var secondaryList = ["bar", "baz"];
var singleList = secondaryList.concat(main);

// this one constraint is exactly the same as the other two
justOneQuery.containedIn('channels', singleList);

// or you could do the same thing with three equalTo
justOneQuery.equalTo('channels', "foo");
justOneQuery.equalTo('channels', "bar");
justOneQuery.equalTo('channels', "baz");
```

I suggest you get your query working as above, with a few hard-coded variables that you know are in the data.  Once you know the query works, you can then concentrate on making sure you call the function properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it doesn't work but it seems that the issue is with the `containedIn` query which doesn't seem to work as I have expected it to.

Comment: I guess I should have looked at your logic.  equalTo on an array col tests if the value of main is in channels.  containedIn does the same thing with all the values in secondaryList.

Comment: Thank you again for the quick response but for some reason the second query just doesn't reduce the number of results from the first. What I need is to filter the results from the first query using the second one.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks